# Specific Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a quick question:

I want every link in the div to alert a message, but only the anchors. I dont want the div to initiate the alert function.

Html:

```
<div id="abc">
  <a href='#'> Button 1 </a>
  <a href='#'> Button 2</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#abc').click(function(){
                alert('a');
            });
        });
```

How do I modify the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you could just bind the event handler on the a tag inside the div.

```
$('#abc a').click(function() {
  alert('a');
});
```

Comment: thanks. i forgot about that. been a while since i used jquery

Answer (score 0):

exchanging `$('#shortlisting')` with `$('#shortlisting a')` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#abc a').on("click", function() {
  alert('a');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#abc a').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/buDXb/)